# magento admin - retrieve current selected store in a multistore backend

Tags: magento-1.4, magento-1.5, magento, magento-1.6

is it possible to retrieve the current selected store view in a multi store magento backend? i'm in an admi page (Catalog -> manage Categories -> general Information) and i have to retrieve the current selected store / store id. is it possible and how?

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a number of options for this but you should be able to use,

```
Mage::app()->getRequest()->getParam('store');
```

if you aren't looking for a specific ID, you can use

```
Mage::getModel('core/store')->getCollection()->load()->getAllIds();
```

assigning your own variables to use with them.